# Связать 2 массива разного типа

Tags: java, android, массивы

Есть 2 массива

```
String[] countries = { "Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
```

Первый массив отображается в листвью в первом активити. Пользователь выбирает несколько стран и после этого во втором отображается среднее арифметическое населения. В общем, как связать 2 массива, так, чтобы 1 элемент массива countries относился к первому элементу массива population, второй - второму, и т.д. Или посоветуйте другой подход

Comment: Можно сделать отдельный класс Country с полем population. Ну или можно сделать мапу с ключом country и значением population.

Comment: @not a Programmer, а можно пример кода

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
    int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};

    Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
    }
    countryData.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " -> " + value));
}
```